# Connect wordpress ftp when it's running under XAMPP

Tags: wordpress, ftp, xampp

I've got an XAMPP on my mac, after that I install wordpress on it. Now I want to connect to it through ftp, but when I connecting to ftp:\localhost I see files from XAMPP start page only and no files from wordpress.

What should I do?

Answer (score 0):

Go to the installed directory of XAMPP and go to the directory htdocs.

There is a index.html file. Delete this file.

OR

try to type in your browser

ftp:\localhost\wordpress\